# ASP.NET: Record Sound From A Web App?

Tags: asp.net, voice-recording

I'm contemplating adding a voice recording to some posts on my site. I'm wondering if there is an ASP.NET library out there that will allow me to:

1. Press a button to start recording
2. Record what I'm saying through my comp's built in microphone
3. Save the file as a .wav or some other popular sound file

As of now, I will be the sole user of this function, but it would still be nice to have in my bag of tricks in case I want to pull it out later for a client.

Comment: hmm doesn't look like this is as easy as it should be.... maybe i will pass on this feature. thanks for everyone's input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You solution will involve a flash componet (outside of rendering the markup that invokes the flash component).  The ASP.NET stack won't be able to do it.  Silverlight doesn't seem able to do it.

[Here is how](http://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/microphone.htm).

Answer (score 2):

It is not doable without the help of a plugin. Browsers simply don't support voice recording.
You could choose from:

- Make a SilverLight applet.
- The flashPlayer can record too.
- find a java Applet that can do this.
- Make an activeX Plugin (since you have affinity to asp)
- use your os provided voice recorder, save the file and upload it. Playback via browser is easy

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem: the browser does not allow this level of hardware access by an application.  You could however achieve this either through Java, Flash or ActiveX (Yuk! don't do it) should the end user allow the access to occur however there are a number of cavaets.  Here's a great thread where like-minded people like yourself are approaching the same challenge:

http://drupal.org/node/69242

If I were cornered to do this I would create a signed Java Applet.

Answer (score 0):

not directly from asp.net since asp.net is server side and you need access to the client side microphone - however the new adobe flash player has the ability to access the mircophone so in theory you could use flash to record then upload to your site.

Comment: You are limited to 100k of storage on the user's machine without explicit permission and any audio you record is captured in a proprietary licensed format.

Answer (score 0):

See [ListenUp sdk](http://www.javasonics.com/). I found a bulletin board called [english-test.net](http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic39886.html#why_should_i_use_the_online_voice_recorder) that is using the sdk to post voices.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some client-side code to achieve this as regular HTML doesn't support audio input and upload.

The ActiveX control [Active Audio Record 2.0](http://www.guangmingsoft.net/audiorecord/) claims to support recording audio and uploading it to an ASP.NET web server. I've never tried it though.